# Connection has timed out, iptables settings

Tags: iptables, connection, timeout

I am running two websites through a VPS using apache virtualhost.  The first website is working. When I try to access the second website on Firefox or Chrome I keep getting the error: `The connection has timed out`.

I added the following line to my iptables:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

and port `80` was open yesterday and today it says it is closed.  Either way my first website still works so I am not sure if this is the problem.

My iptables config is:

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]  
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]  
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]  
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2234 -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited  
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited COMMIT
```

When I run the `dig` command it correctly points the **A record** to my VPS IP address.
What could be the problem here? I can't see what I am doing wrong.

**Update**:  I tried hashing as recommended, that did not work.  How can I check to see port 80 is open for both sites?  I thought once port `80` is open, anything can connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

you have defined `port 80` twice with two different rule-sets? there could be a conflict due to this? can you check by `hashing` one of them?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/304007)

Comment: thanks for the reply. So I tried each rule individually and then together, neither works. I included both lines so when you read this you will know what i am talking about. What gets me is one website works and the other won't? 

(-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT )  

(-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT)   

Can you please tell me what you mean by hashing? again i am new to this. thanks.

Comment: Do both sites point to port 80?

Comment: @kasperd i did not have the reputation to comment :-) thats why i had to drop it as an answer.

Comment: @learningit  as @kalyan has mentioned, does both sites run on `port : 80`? also by hashing i meant commenting this second rule  `-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` and do a `iptables restart`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the additional information posted in these comments.

Comment: @kaylan i tried hashing as recommended, that did not work.  I thought once port 80 is open it would be open for anything that wants to connect on port 80?  How do i check both sites are open for port 80?